# I'm learning pygame and am experiencing an error with collisions

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, pygame, collision

> ```
> File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 1682, in spritecollide
>   default_sprite_collide_func = sprite.rect.colliderect
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'colliderect'
> ```

^ this error is given after running the highlighted piece of code, in "**", below. I have no idea how to fix this. The goal of this line is to detect if evil cookies collide with the player sprite, and I'm not sure if there is any way for me to do this "more efficiently" or if I'm taking the completely wrong appproach.

```
# Part four  - collisions

import pygame,sys
import random

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos_x, pos_y):
        super().__init__()
        self.sprites = []
        self.is_animating = False
        self.sprites.append(pygame.image.load("ghostanim1.png").convert_alpha())
        self.sprites.append(pygame.image.load("ghostanim2.png").convert_alpha())
    
        self.csprite = 0
        self.image = self.sprites[self.csprite]

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = [pos_x,pos_y]

    def update(self):
        if self.is_animating == True:
            self.csprite += 0.05

            if int(self.csprite) >= len(self.sprites):
                self.csprite = 0
                self.is_animating = False
                # Bug fixing - list cannot go above 0 so image won't lead to error
            self.image = self.sprites[int(self.csprite)]

    def animate(self):
        self.is_animating = True

    def move(self,pos_x,pos_y):
        self.rect = self.rect = [pos_x-player_speed_x, pos_y-player_speed_y]

class EvilCookie(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,picture_path,pos_x,pos_y):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load(picture_path)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (screen_width/2,screen_height/2))
        self.rect.center = [pos_x,pos_y]

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += 1

class EdibleCookie(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,picture_path,pos_x,pos_y):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load(picture_path)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (screen_width/2,screen_height/2))
        self.rect.center = [pos_x,pos_y]

class Cooker(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,picture_path,pos_x,pos_y):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load(picture_path)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (screen_width/2,screen_height/2))
        self.rect.center = [pos_x,pos_y]
    
        
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        
# Main window - defines window definitons and the screen itself, the "surface"
screen_width = 1280
screen_height = 960
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Cookie Cafe') # Sets window title

# Images - loads images with pixel accuracy (convert_alpha)
background = pygame.image.load("background.png").convert_alpha()
bigenemy = pygame.image.load("enemybig.png").convert_alpha()
smallenemy = pygame.image.load("enemysmall.png").convert_alpha()
goodenemy = pygame.image.load("goodcookie.png").convert_alpha()

# Rectangles - Creates rectangles which defines where images/characters can be 
cookerrect = pygame.Rect(1000, 550, 200, 200)
backgroundrect = background.get_rect()
backgroundrect.center = (screen_width/2, screen_height/2)

# Sprite group: MOVING SPRITES
moving_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player(300,700)
moving_sprites.add(player)

# Sprite group: Cooker
cooker = Cooker("cooker.png",1000,600)
cooker_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
cooker_group.add(cooker)

# Sprite group: Edible Cookies
goodcookie = EdibleCookie("goodcookie.png",random.randrange(600,800),random.randrange(0,800))
goodcookie_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
goodcookie_group.add(goodcookie)

# Sprite group: Evil Cookies
evil = EvilCookie("enemysmall.png",random.randrange(0, screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height/2))
evil2 = EvilCookie("enemysmall.png",random.randrange(0, screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height/2))
evil3 = EvilCookie("enemysmall.png",random.randrange(0, screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height/2))
evil4 = EvilCookie("enemysmall.png",random.randrange(0, screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height/2))
evil5 = EvilCookie("enemysmall.png",random.randrange(0, screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height/2))
evil6 = EvilCookie("enemysmall.png",random.randrange(0, screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height/2))
evil7 = EvilCookie("enemysmall.png",random.randrange(0, screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height/2))
evil8 = EvilCookie("enemysmall.png",random.randrange(0, screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height/2))
evil9 = EvilCookie("enemysmall.png",random.randrange(0, screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height/2))
evil10 = EvilCookie("enemysmall.png",random.randrange(0, screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height/2))
evil11 = EvilCookie("enemysmall.png",random.randrange(0, screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height/2))
evil12 = EvilCookie("enemysmall.png",random.randrange(0, screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height/2))
evil13 = EvilCookie("enemysmall.png",random.randrange(0, screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height/2))
evil14 = EvilCookie("enemysmall.png",random.randrange(0, screen_width),random.randrange(0,screen_height/2))

evil_cookies = pygame.sprite.Group()
evil_cookies.add(evil,evil2,evil3,evil4,evil5,evil6,evil7,evil8,evil9,evil10,evil11,evil12,evil13,evil14)

# Speed and movement control
player_speed_x = 0
player_speed_y = 0
screen.blit(background,backgroundrect) # Prints images 

origin_x = 300
origin_y = 700

# Music
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("music.wav")
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.5)
pygame.mixer.music.play()
# Loop
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        player.move(int(origin_x),int(origin_y))
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # Checking inputs, here, QUIT is checked (leave game)
            pygame.quit() 
            sys.exit()
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            player.animate()
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player_speed_y -= 15
                origin_y -= 15
                
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player_speed_y += 15
                origin_y += 15

            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player_speed_x -= 15
                origin_x -= 15
                
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player_speed_x += 15
                origin_x += 15

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player_speed_y += 15

            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player_speed_y -= 15
                
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player_speed_x += 15
                
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player_speed_x -= 15

    hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player,evil_cookies, False)
    if hit:
        print("hit")
    
    player.move(origin_x,origin_y)           
    screen.blit(background,backgroundrect)
    moving_sprites.draw(screen)
    moving_sprites.update()
    evil_cookies.draw(screen)
    evil_cookies.update()
    cooker_group.draw(screen)
    cooker_group.update()
    goodcookie_group.draw(screen)
    goodcookie_group.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60) # Keeps FPS at 60 to prevent lag or un-playable game
```

Comment: **hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player,evil_cookies, False)
    if hit:
        print("hit")** - specific line which leads to error is here

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the line

> ```py
> self.rect = self.rect = [pos_x-player_speed_x, pos_y-player_speed_y]
> ```

in the `move` method of the class `Player`. This line turns `self.rect` into a list. Change it to:

```py
self.rect.topleft = (self.rect.x-player_speed_x, self.rect.y-player_speed_y)
```

or

```py
self.rect.move_ip(-player_speed_x, -player_speed_y)
```

---

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...] 

    def move(self,pos_x,pos_y):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.rect.x-player_speed_x, self.rect.y-player_speed_y)
```